# Why is it called first-child?

Tags: css

I'm expecting a flurry of down votes, but nonetheless, I would like to know what y'all think.

If you have,

```
<div>
    <p>Paragraph1</p>
    <p>Paragraph2</p>
</div>
<div>
</div>
```

taken literally, I would expect `div:first-child` to select for `<p>Paragraph1</p>` because `<p>Paragraph1</p>` is the first child node of `div`
But, as we know, it selects the first `div` in the html, wouldn't it make more sense to call this simply `:first` or maybe `:first-sibling`?

Comment: This sounds like a geek Seinfeld routine! Love it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery has an extended selector: [`:first`](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/), Just note that the problem with `:first` is it stops finding elements after the first match, unlike `:first-child` so here's example why `:first` isn't a good name.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Mozilla's reference documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Pseudo-classes) (emphasis mine):

> A CSS pseudo-class is a keyword added to selectors that specifies a
>   **special state of the element to be selected**.

The pseudo-class is a modifier to the existing selector.  So the result must be a subset of what would be matched by the existing selector.  Therefore, `div:first-child` can't return anything other than a `div`.

Comment: makes perfect sense, but why not call it `:first`? it seems very odd that they added -child.

Comment: Just like `a:hover` doesn't mean `a>:hover` and `div:before` doesn't reference whatever came before div. All pseudos work this way, it's no different.

Comment: And as to why not `:first` because first in relation to what? The first div on the whole page? Just in this section? `:first-child` gives context, be it the docuemnt, a div, a ul. Whatever.

Comment: @idrumgood yes, but Im not asking why it works the way it does, I'm asking why they named it `:first-child`.

Comment: @idrumgood `:first` in relation to whatever the rest of the selector says. The `:first` one of _____.

Comment: @watson: Another way to look at it is that pseudo-class represents an "is a" or "has been" relationship.  So `a:hover` = `a has been hovered`.  Or `a:visited` = `a has been visited`.  Likewise `div:first-child` = `div is a first child`.  Beyond that you'll have to track down the original developer or spec writer and ask them :)

Comment: @watson, `:first` maybe give me only first match, as jQuery defined it.

Answer (score 0):

:first-child means it is the first child of its parent. I think :first is not specific enough and :first-sibling .... that seems too equivalent to first-child as in both are very ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

And as to why not `:first` because first in relation to what? The first div on the whole page? Just in this section? `:first-child` gives context, be it the docuemnt, a div, a ul. Whatever.

What you reference as 'taken literally' would actually seem to be `div > :first-child` because you're thinking to select an element within the div.

`div:first` would mean, if taken literally, the first div you encounter. So it would always be the first div on the page.

`div:first-child` taken literally would mean "A div that it is the first child of it's parent" You need to remember that psuedo classes descrive the element to which they are applied.